# How to view what sensors-detect scanned?

Tags: sensors, lm-sensors

I am using lm-sensors and Ran sensors-detect. Can I view what sensors-detect scanned for? At the end of running sensors detect I got a report, but I didn’t remember it. I want to see what sensors-detect scanned for and what it did. I also want to know the default temperature sensors out of the box that Lm-sensors recognize without having to run sensors-detect.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Do you want to see *the devices* that `lm-sensors` accessed, or the data? If you're looking for a running tally of the data, `glances` is my go-to for ... well ... everything. It's `top` on steroids.

Comment: Thank you for helping me clarify. I wanted to see the devices that lm-sensors accessed.